# Importance of implementing Angular Guards

Tags: javascript, angular

In our application, we have restricted routes(navigation) based on user role. Is it absolutely necessary to implement Angular Guards to provide/restrict access to routes?

Does it in some way provide additional security as opposed to restricting access based on user role from JavaScript/HTML/plain Angular (i.e. by showing and hiding links and showing/hiding data)?

Comment: They are just a convenient way to do it. There is no additional security in using them. Security has to be enforced on the server anyway.

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/, https://www.positronx.io/angular-route-resolvers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular Guards are solely a routing concern. They are elements that prevent the router from navigating to a specific page, no matter how they may trigger that navigation (through a link, a button, or direct input of url into the location bar).

However, as with any javascript framework, this 'security' is not really security but more user convenience. Because of the nature of the web, anyone can interfere with any data/code on the client (i.e. the browser), and as such, nothing implemented in client-side javascript should be considered real security. You have to implement your real security checks on your backend system.

Also note that since Angular Guards are solely an Angular Router concern, then if you are not using the official Angular router, they make no sense.

Comment: We are using the official Angular Router; but not Route Guards. How can I prevent users from accessing data by entering direct URL in the address bar of the browser? Current restriction is only on links and buttons by hiding them based on user roles.

Comment: that's literally the purpose of route guards - to prevent that.  if you don't want to use route guards, then you can do your 'route guard' checks in your individual components and have them navigate the user away if the checks fail, but literally, that's the same purpose of the route guard, so why not use the functionality as it is provided?

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article where I explain everything regarding Guards and Interceptors ect http://agdev.tech/2021/03/18/angular-authentication-interceptors-and-guards/
There is also a stackblitz provided that might be helpful.

Comment: While a link is nice, can you add the answer content here?